# Taking the LCM of algebraic expressions

Tags: algebra

Is it possible in *Mathematica* to take the `LCM` of an algebraic expression? For example, I want to take the `LCM` of $9$, $9y$, $12y^2$ and $27y^4$.

If I type in

```
LCM [9, 9y, 12y^2, 27^4]
```

it returns the same value. I'm running *Mathematica* version 9. Could you help me out?

Comment: What answer do you expect to see from `LCM[9,9y,12y^2,27^4]`?

Comment: May be you want   `PolynomialLCM[9, 9 y, 12 y^2, 27^4]` which gives `2125764 y^2`

Comment: There appears to be a typographical error cf LatTex list and code:` PolynomialLCM[9, 9 y, 12 y^2, 27y^4]` yields 108y^4

Comment: @Nasser You coould post this as a response. That way the question won't end up with 0 responses.

Answer (score 4):

To get the least common multiple of the polynomials, use `PolynomialLCM`.

From Mathematica help on the above it says `by default treat algebraic numbers that appear  in poly_i the as independent variables`

Hence the answer you want is

```
PolynomialLCM[9, 9 y, 12 y^2, 27^4]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

More information on `PolynomialLCM` and more examples are here

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PolynomialLCM.html